# Powershell and Forms

Tags: forms, powershell

I'm trying to get forms working with powershell, and I'm nearly there. I've got a checklist box full of ~10 items, and I'd like to perform an action on the selected items when you click the Report button.

I've never worked with forms (either in C#, .NET, or powershell) so this is a learning experience... Is there any examples of how to, upon clicking a button, get the a list of items selected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Select-GuiFilteredObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaybaz_ms/archive/2007/09/12/powshell-gui-for-selecting-objects-in-a-pipeline-select-graphiphicalfilteredobject-ps1.aspx), originally by Lee and enhanced a little by me.  This will help you get started with forms.

I bet it would be a bunch nicer if done with the latest PowerShell v2 features.